Offering shelter to homeless employees
Hypothetical question.
Is there anyway for an employer to legally allow a low-wage homeless employee to regularly doss-down overnight in a empty store-room in a commercial premises?
Lets say John owns a fast food restaurant (or something similar), he runs a legitimate business and likes to do things by-the-book. His employees are all paid living wage, but local rental costs are so high that some of them are sleeping rough. John would like to help, he has a unused store room with power, running water, sink and toilet, but no shower, heating or cooking area. It does however provide better shelter than the local underpass!
The storeroom doesn't have planning permission for residential use, and bringing it up to regulations for rental use is totally un-economic (probably £30-60k or more). If it were brought to a rentable standard, then the size of the investment would require to John to rent it a market-rate, and even if John were to somehow offer it as a freebie to some of his employees, then any such freebie would be taxed as income by the taxman - leaving the employee worse off.
Back to the original question - is there any legal way of letting one or more of the employees living in the storeroom - possibly for several months?

"It does however provide better shelter than the local underpass!" The very existence of housing codes shows that lawmakers do not find this argument persuasive.

"His employees are all paid living wage, but local rental costs are so high that some of them are sleeping rough" - This statement seems contradictory.

@HectorLector - the 'living wage' is currently £11.44 per hour. This is set by the government and doesn't necessarily reflect the true cost of living.

How "legal" do you want it to be? If the employer has plausible deniability that they knew the employee tasked with closing up was staying the night, then it's just a matter of making sure nothing ever happens that would require said employer to officially take notice...

Along similar lines, I work in a public EU building. We have a library room on my floor with an unpleasant, narrow, backless bench. Our building supervisor has forced the floor's director to get that bench out: According to planning, the library is a store room (literally a book-store) and therefore exempt from air quality regulations (=occasional monitoring, but more importantly constant fresh air delivery). Any seating device invites longer-than-necessary presence risks death-by-asphyxiation!! So, disallowed. Unless your office is built to hotel specifications, it's financially impossible.

Even in London, someone with a full-time job paid minimum wage (that would be around £1800/mo for a 40-hour week) should be able to find (much) better options than living rough, even on the private rental market (there are quite a few places between £500 and £600/mo on Zoopla right now for instance). They may have to spend quite a bit of time commuting, and they may have to pay a pretty expensive Travelcard, and it may take some time to find a landlord willing to take them, but it you really want to help them, it's probably a better idea for everyone to help them find a real place.

@ConanTheGerbil This might be a quirk of US vs. UK English, but the legally defined 'minimum wage' and the term 'living wage' are generally not treated as synonyms in US English.  There is a very large political debate in the US on the best way to get these two into line.  Including if that is even the government's responsibility.

@Chuu they weren't treated as synonyms in the UK either, until the last government (Conservative) rebranded the legal  National Minimum Wage as the National Living Wage.  The Real Living Wage is an independent calculation, higher and more realistic,  that some employers have signed up to.

@jcaron I know about employer-provided annual season ticket loans, which I think can be done in a  tax-efficient way through salary sacrifice.  Loans to cover a rental deposit would be interesting, but are capital-intensive for a small business

@jcaron this sounds very much like a Conservative “people just need to pull themselves up by their bootstraps” attitude. You are proposing that someone spend a third of their gross income on rent, commute for how-many hours a day plus the costs involved in that, all for a minimum wage job. You’d do that, would you? And this is in a rapidly shrinking rental market, where estate agents don’t even need to waste time showing prospective tenants around, as available properties go within hours anyway.

@ConanTheGerbil Thanks for clarifying (I am neither in the US/UK, so was not familiar with the details of the term)

@Darren What I'm saying is just that (provided they are over 21 and working full time, even if only at minimum wage) the barrier to having a real place to live in probably isn't so much its cost compared to their earnings (which, while important, is quite normal... I have paid a third of my pre-tax income on rent for years), and that's why helping them get that place would probably make more sense than trying to find weird arrangements which would necessarily be temporary and possibly cost them more than an actual place (when you factor in food and hygiene, for instance).

@Darren according to government statistics for 2022-2023, private renters in England spent 32% of their income on housing costs, with the lowest quintile spending 59%. The lowest quintile would include people whose income is too low to pay tax, so gross income and net income would be the same.

@James_pic None of which makes it OK!

This question flits between very different scenarios and assertions. The discrepancy between living wage and employees sleeping rough has already been pointed out, but also: "If it were brought to a rentable standard, then the size of the investment would require to John to rent it a market-rate" You're either asserting that market rate is reasonable relative to the cost of making a space that is humane to inhabit, or you're asserting that rental standards are unnecessarily high in order for them to match the unreasonable market rate that is causing employees to have to sleep rough.

[..] In other words, I do not see space for a scenario where John's honest rental rate would be unaffordable by reasonably paid employees. If local rental costs are unreasonably high, then John would be able to offer a less unreasonable rental cost, even if he invests in making that space up to rental standards. If John is not capable of lowering the rental cost without losing money; then that effectively proves that the local rental cost is not unreasonably high, and it therefore calls into question whether John is paying his employees a fair wage based on his restaurant's location.

[..] Referring back to the original quote, it starts to sound more like John would prefer to then actually charge the going market rate for this rentable space (because he can), instead of offering it to his homeless employees as an act of charity. It starts suggesting that this question is really just asking "how low of a rental standard could John get away with to still justify housing his underpaid employees who cannot afford to live near to where they are expected to work", which throws up massive ethical red flags about John having slumlord ambitions.

There is no legal way of doing this
At least, not without receiving planning permission which is likely to be refused unless the living accommodation meets minimum standards. This would include (shared) bathing and cooking facilities.
Without such permission, Bob is in breach of local planning permission.
In addition, Bob is also likely in breach of his lease (if a tenant) or his commonhold obligations (if applicable) as these will almost invariably have a prohibition on residential use. He has also breached his insurance contract for the same reason so if the building burns down and all the employees suffer excruciating deaths, Bob is liable without insurance cover.

Also it will vastly complicate the situation if an employment tribunal becomes involved.

At least the cooking facilities should not be a problem. This is a fast-food restaurant, after all, so they do have a kitchen.

@PMF if it is a restaurant then there might be issues related with health/sanitary regulations added.

At least in the US, fire codes would also be a problem. For example, I've been told many times that in order to be legally described as a "bedroom", a room in a residence must have a window so there is emergency egress in a fire if the door is blocked by fire. While I doubt laws are identical in the UK, there's probably something similar.

Homeless Bob Initiative
Yes, but it might be considered a little creative to say the least. John only has to change Bob's job description from waiter to night watchman and pay him for the eight hours he is on duty at night while the establishment is closed. There is no law that prevents an employee from nodding off while he is on the clock. It's strictly a matter between the employer and the employee. For fun, John could provide security cop uniform pajamas (widely available online) and a comfortable couch in the break room.
During the day, Bob could act as a volunteer to perform his regular duties of waiting on tables. This makes it possible for him to be covered by insurance while he is on the premises at any hour. The added benefit of having a watchman available might even lead to lower insurance rates due to the lower risk and/or prevention of robberies and fire.
I've seen this done on construction sites and it greatly reduces losses of construction materials. It's very effective and helpful to everyone all around. It's very common for night watchmen to be allowed to engage in other activities while they remain at their post, even if snoozing isn't specifically mentioned.
In the UK, employers cannot legally force employees to work longer than their contracted hours, but no law prevents workers from choosing to stay on the premises if the employer allows it. There needs to be no contract at all for this arrangement.
There are no laws in the UK that define the rights of volunteers or the legal definition of a volunteer.  A person who is paid for his shift as a night watchman can volunteer to wait tables during the day. Employees are entitled to at least 11 hours of consecutive rest in every 24-hour period, but they are not forced to rest and they are not prevented from 'lending a hand' if  they wish to during their off hours. Labor laws are designed to prevent employers from abusing their workers, but no law prevents them from being kind, generous, flexible, and charitable.
As long as John and Bob are okay with the deal, no one else has any say in the matter. Even if the locals did find out about it, they would most likely admire John and be glad that Bob wasn't sleeping under the bridge. No judge could prevent it unless it came into a court of law.
This legal strategy is based on maintaining a non-adversarial relationship between two parties. No lawyer would recommend it for obvious reasons: 1) the high probability that it would become adversarial, and 2) the lack of recourse for either party if it did.  The question asks if there is a legal way for Homeless Bob to remain on the premises in a non-residential facility as a non-resident. This is one possible way, regardless of the probability of a poor outcome.
In practice, this situation is more often handled in the manner that @Perkins suggests in his comment on the question:  "If the employer has plausible deniability that they knew the employee tasked with closing up was staying the night, then it's just a matter of making sure nothing ever happens that would require said employer to officially take notice."
In my own personal experience, I've purchased abandoned homes that were far below residential standards, and I am like John in the OP's question in the sense that "John would like to help". My Homeless Bob is retired on a low fixed income and wants to occupy and purchase a home, but cannot afford a down payment and cannot get a loan. To avoid liability, I am free to transfer ownership free and clear "as is" and rely on his word that he will make payments as he can going forward.
No one, especially not a lawyer, would advise me to do so.  Bob could decide to pay nothing and get a free house. It's madness. It's crazy and it's not advised, but it's legal. I have to wonder if this is more insane or less insane than enormous masses of humans clutching and scratching at each other's eyes to 'get over' on one another.
One important advantage is that this makes Trust and Honor possible by allowing space for trustworthiness and honor to flourish. Banks, lawyers, and real estate agents get completely cut out of the deal and are no longer able to prey on us. The 'Homeless Bob Initiative' is also known as "Occupy This!"

I wonder if it would be legal if the person’s only “employment” for the company was night time security and they were allowed to be onsite only during their security shift.

Note that if you're "employing" them as a night watchman, all employment laws (including minimum wage) apply during time "worked". I believe the suggestion is to officially pay them for the night and have them work days unpaid, which, depending on jurisdiction & environment, might not be possible. Also "working" during both night and day (even unpaid) might be counted toward overtime considerations (especially if the night shift doesn't have "weekends off").

I'm not sure the night-watchman ruse would work (not under UK laws). Fulltime unpaid internships aren't legal here. Having someone working 50 hours a week waiting tables, and then another 50 hours a week as a security guard would almost certainly be breaking the law - especially if one of the two jobs was unpaid!

Thanks, R.M.  I wrestled with that (and other things) before I started writing my answer. The only precautions I could find were to either have Bob volunteer to wait tables during the day, or to accept it as an educational opportunity. As an informal agreement it could work if Bob and John trusted each other. If they devised a contract between them, and something went horribly wrong, then a judge would clearly see that they were trying to create a loophole in whatever laws might apply in that jurisdiction. It's hard to say how the judge would rule.

I think you would also run into problems with having them "work" 7 days a week/365 days a year if they used that as their place to sleep.

Sounds full of legal pitfalls. If one wanted to do pull such a stunt, consider declaring a "staff rest room" and allowing them to go there during breaks and also before and after their shift, but not 24/7. But even that would need to be checked with a lawyer ...

First: That would violate labor laws. 7 days a week, 8 hours a day is 56 hrs/week, well above the legal maximum, and I will guess there is a mandatory weekly day off.

Second and more important: JUDGES ARE NOT STUPID!! Just because you call him "watchman", even if you sign some paper to that effect, does not mean that a judge will agree that he is staying as a watchman. There will be witness testifying that he was living there (with some place to sleep, no actual home, etc.) There will be no records of his activity. The judge will notice that man has no actual home, and that he is staying way too long. Adding fraudulent contracts to this "creativity" would not protect you, but would become evidence of your intent at deception.

I added the last three paragraphs to address the concerns in the comments.

As long as John and Bob are okay with the deal, no one else has any say in the matter. You could not be more wrong. To put an example, in Spain sometimes business try to avoid labour laws by hiring workers as contractors. But if the judge decides that they are actually workers and not contractors, then the judge can decide that the worker has been hired since the relationship began and that everything (workers'right, social security payments) must be regularized. There are other actors here, e.g. authorities that care about housing, security, work relationships...

@SJuan76  In this scenario Bob is a worker, not a contractor. He is formally hired as a night watchman with workers rights and social security payments.  John is not trying to avoid labor laws, he's just trying to help the guy get back on his feet.  Everything is perfectly by-the-book regarding the nightwatchman job. That's the beauty of it!

You want Bob to work both during the day and the night (because "officially" he is a nightwatch). That would break labour laws. And again, if the contract does not reflect the reality, a judge will not restrict himself to accepting what is written on it. And the idea of two positions (one paid and one as an intern!) at the same business is laughable.

@SJuan76 I removed the word 'intern' so we only need to consider his volunteer work during the day and his paid employment at night. John doesn't require Bob to work during the day. Bob waits on tables in the day as a favor because he appreciates John letting him sleep on the job all night. There's no law that prevents this in the UK or the EU. Bob doesn't have two positions. He has one. Please read the edited version.

If it's legal to mix paid work and "volunteering" for a for-profit employer, how are the minimum wage and overtime ever enforced? Wouldn't an employer paying below minimum wage or not paying overtime just claim that all employees are volunteering to work some of their hours for free? I'm not sure about the UK, but in other jurisdictions I'm familiar with, you have to pay employees for all the hours they work; you can't just say that some are volunteer hours.

@ZachLipton or their contract states explicitly that overtime isn't compensated. Happens a lot in my line of work. Overtime is unpaid or more often paid in time (1 hour off for every hour of overtime). Overtime as such isn't 'volunteering' as that would cause a whole different set of laws to come into effect ruling the labour relationship.

"Even if the locals did find out about it, they would most likely admire John and be glad that Bob wasn't sleeping under the bridge." I wish the world was as nice as that. I can see a lot of haters.

@ZachLipton, it only works if the "volunteering" is genuinely voluntary.  If "Bob" can, without penalty, tell "John" he's not in the mood to wait tables today, it's fine.  If he can't, it's unpaid overtime.

@Mark (and ave), I think this is covered by "This legal strategy is based on maintaining a non-adversarial relationship between two parties. No lawyer would recommend it for obvious reasons: 1) the high probability that it would become adversarial, and 2) the lack of recourse for either party if it did."

More of a comment than an answer, but so far eveyone seems to obviate the laboral part of this.
The laboral relationship makes everything more difficult
For the sake of the answer, I will assume that the housing is not up to the minimal standards setup for a rental (because if it is good enough, there is no legal issue).
An employer can provide housing for employees. It is not that unusual for seasonal workers, or for certain industries, provided that the housing is meets legal standards.
But, that housing, is a payment in kind. It is something that the employee receives as part of the work relationship. In fact, it can be valued and taxed accordingly. For you as an employer, it is something of value that you give to your employee, in exchange for his work.
So, what you are proposing is paying employees with housing that does not meet the legal standards. Think of it as if you were feeding them, but with rotten food. Or paying with scrip. Which means that, apart from the issues purely derived from the quality of the housing, there may be issues related to laws protecting workers'rights.
(*1) Which would not make legal but could give you some leeway with the relevant authorities.
The fact that you also give your employees a salary makes little difference. By giving that housing, you are making your job offer more attractive for a given salary, so you cannot say it is not related.

There's also a social aspect to this: Employee housing is often used for jobs that pay better and have more job security. Connecting one's ability to have a safe place to sleep to their low wage, high turnover job sets bad power dynamics. Do consider that if they're fired they might need to be asked to immediately take all their belongings and leave, and if they're given extra time, that may lead to them refusing to leave, or give them time to cause harm to the premises if they so desire (one would hope not).

@ave : This is exactly why the law does not really favor such relationships: it can be abused and it can be slowly turned into indentured servitude (the larger scale version is company towns where the company owns everything, including the housing, and can exploit the workforce because they have nowhere else to go). Also a lonely good Samaritan employer can see it backfire: the homeless employee might refuse to move out and it can get very costly to forcibly evict him, especially if he damages the property out of spite.

@ave Is it really?  I associate it with seasonal agricultural workers sleeping in caravans.

@ave I do not think that the law "does not favor" these relationships. They have become (both physically and socially) has improved; people do not need to be that close to their jobs and many people do not have the same job for life. Owning homes is also a capital cost that business do not want. Not to mention the problems of managing homes. But the law takes in into account, and it is certainly used (temporary workers, housekeepers, etc...) The problem is when the place is not up to standards.

I'd argue that even if the housing is up to minimal standards setup for a rental. then one could still run afoul of laws if a) zoning does not allow rentals in a business district (for example) or b) officially renting the room but "gifting" the rent (i.e., not charging rent) would cause an undue tax burden on the employee and/or employer.

Even if your person does not live at their work, a "break room" where people can get clean and change their clothes, maybe even wash their clothes by hand and hang them up for the day, would make them much more comfortable and healthy.  A policy that anyone who needs to can arrive an hour or so before their shift starts and use this room, would be a nice one. (You could also say they could stay after as long as the establishment was still open or something like that.) Lots of very expensive employers have such a room for people who bike to work or run before work. They even install showers and lockers. Lockers might enable a rough-sleeper to have a safe place for some of their possessions, I don't mean to imply people need to protect their possessions from their coworkers.
This has the advantage of not being illegal. There is no housing, and therefore no housing standard. Break rooms in which people can meet personal and hygiene needs are an everyday thing. Lockers and sinks and even showers are normal. People changing clothes at work before their shift, also super normal.
There are probably insurance reasons why folks can't sleep there, and depending on your employer for a bed doesn't feel fair, but enabling someone to live a more normal life is possible even without a bed. Note I am not saying wink wink have a couch in there, who knows, some people might have a nap, or anything like that. Simply to meet the many non-sleeping needs, like getting clean, that rough sleepers may have.
